# IOS Resizing UITextView for IM Program

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, resize, uitextview

Currently I have a program that displays chat messages between users.  It puts each message in a cell and stores the message in a UITextView that's contained in the cell.  The UITextView has a background that is applied to the view.  How exactly do I resize the text view so that the background is resized and the dynamic content is properly placed in side?  Also, what would you recommend would be be the best way to resize the cell along with the view.  I know there are a lot of similar posts but I can't seem to find anything that works with this specific situation.  Either they resize the content without view and background or when the cell resizes it is glitchy and inconsistent with the size of the text views content.  Here is the code im using inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MessageCell *cell;
    Message *message = [_messages objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)];

    if ([[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] isEqualToString:message.sender])
    {
        cell = (MessageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SenderCell"];
        cell.message.text = message.message;
    }
    else
    {
        cell = (MessageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RecipientCell"];
        cell.message.text = message.message;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the free Sensible TableView framework. The have a text view that automatically resizes as your content grows.

Comment: I ended up using a solution that was derived from hpgrowingtextview, dana0550's suggestion and DharaParekh's solution.  However, im having issues with they way apple reuses cells.  I am watching the sensible tableview framework rate now.  From what I have seen this may be exactly what im looking for. How old is it and is it still supported? @Matt

Comment: Not sure how old but it's currently very active. You should probably be able to know by looking for old posts in their forum or by asking the people in the chat room there. I've been using it for almost a year now and I am really happy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of the following methods of the NSString class to calculate the textView size and from there dynamic resize the textView frame. For example:

```
textView.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"" size:18.0]];
```

There are a number of other methods that can calculate the size if you read the NSString class reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use [hpgrowingtextview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hpgrowingtextview) for resizing the textview.

and use [EditableViewCell](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/autoresizingeditabletableviewcell)
for cell resizing based on text size

**OR   for editable tableview cell**

write following methods for reloading data of uitableview. for this you use custom cell for uitableview.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [arrChatMessage count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *textc1 = [arrChatMessage objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    CGSize constraintc1 = CGSizeMake(320, 2000);   
    //320 means width of your label in which you want to display chat message
    CGSize sizec1 = [textc1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:12.0] constrainedToSize:constraintc1 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    //font and font size of your label in which you want to display chat message
    return sizec1.height;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ChatListCustomCell *cell = (ChatListCustomCell *)[tblChatList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatListCustomCell"];

    if (cell != nil)
        cell = nil;

    NSArray* nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatListCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.showsReorderControl = NO;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    //..............

    NSString *textc1 = [arrChatMessage objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    CGSize constraintc1 = CGSizeMake(320, 2000);   
    //320 means width of your label in which you want to display chat message
    CGSize sizec1 = [textc1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:12.0] constrainedToSize:constraintc1 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    //font and font size of your label in which you want to display chat message

    cell.lblChatMessage.text = [arrChatMessage objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    cell.lblChatMessage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,sizec1.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a subclass of UITextView just for that:

https://github.com/MatejBalantic/MBAutoGrowingTextView

It is an auto-layout based light-weight UITextView subclass which automatically grows and shrinks based on the size of user input and can be constrained by maximal and minimal height - all without a single line of code.

Made primarily for use in Interface builder and only works with Auto layout.

This would solve resizing of UITextView. To make sure also table view cells are resized, assign a UITextView delegate and define this method in it:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

Using that you'll be able to detect each time text was entered/removed and than make sure that UITextView's new size is applied to tableview cells as well.